# Display QDateTime in Windows with seconds without converting it to a string

Tags: qt

I know QDateTime displays a time stamp in the way that Windows does it.
Can I change the format **without converting QDateTime to a string**, because this would disable a special filter function?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mentioning `QDateTime` display, I assume you use a `QDateTimeEdit` to display it.

The format that is used for displaying is directly related to the localizations settings. You can use your own display setting by calling `setDisplayFormat(const QString &format)` of the `QDateTimeEdit` object.

The displayFormat is not changing the data stored inside.

For example:

```
ui->dateTimeEdit->setDisplayFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

If this is not the case for you, more information is needed about your particular usage.

Comment: I don't use a QDateTimeEdit.  //Timestamp  `setItem(NewRow, MDL_FAST_DATA_COL_TIMESTAMP, createItem(NewRowItem, QDateTime::fromTime_t(Row.get_Timestamp()), RowColor, FontColor));`  An item in a table is created and filled with a timestamp. get_Timestamp extracts the timestamp (dd.mm.yyyy.hh.mm.ss) out of a database. The Problem is that qt displays the timestamp without seconds because it uses the localization settings. Since it is possible to filter the timestamps by date,it is not possible to use strings, otherwise the filter doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by returning my `QDateTime` as `QVariant<QString>` when calling `model->data(idx, role)` with the `Qt::DisplayRole`. Then, I used user defined roles for sorting and filtering such that when these roles were used in calls to `model->data(idx, role)`, I could return `QVariant<QDateTime>`.